# Heegaard splitting of figure-8 knot complement

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, knot-theory

It is well-known that the figure-8 knot complement in $S^3$ can be described as a circle fibration of a once-punctured torus. Is there also a description of the figure-8 knot as a Heegaard splitting with a genus-two splitting surface? I have read something about `unknotting tunnels' but couldn't find a clear worked out example for the figure-8 knot. Specifically, I would like to know the genus-two mapping class group element that defines the Heegaard splitting.

Comment: Also the boundary of a neighborhood of the fiber is a genus-two splitting surface. So you can recover the genus-two map from the monodromy.

Comment: @MaximPrasolov = Usually a Heegaard splitting surface is connected and closed (that is, without boundary).  If you take $X$ to be the neighbourhood of a fibre, and take $Y$ to be the complement of $X$ then their intersection is not connected and has boundary.

Comment: Unknotting tunnels for 2-bridge knots more generally were classified by Kobayashi. https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9911254

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a sequence of figures showing how to go from a knot diagram (for the figure-eight knot) to a Heegaard splitting of the knot exterior.

[image: Sequence of figures showing how to derive a Heegaard splitting of the figure-eight knot complement]

Your request for “the mapping class group element” is confused.  Mapping classes are (equivalence classes of) homeomorphisms from a surface $S$ to itself.  On the other hand, we obtain a Heegaard splitting by (in this case) gluing the boundary of a handlebody to the boundary of a compression-body.  The two boundaries do not have a canonical identification, so we can’t think of the splitting as a self-mapping.

Comment: Thank you. So is the final picture the splitting surface? Between a genus-two handlebody and a compression body with one genus-two boundary and one interior torus boundary?

Comment: Yes, exactly correct.  The red curve is the boundary of a meridional disk in the “inside” while $a$ and $b$ are disks in the “outside”.

Comment: @Oblonski In the closed case, a Heegaard splitting is defined by gluing the boundaries of two handlebodies together by an element of the mapping class group. This is well-defined up to mapping classes which fix the handlebody. Hence  the Heegaard splitting can be regarded as a double coset of mapping classes with respect to the subgroup fixing the handlebody up to isotopy (for which there are explicit presentations). I think that  a similar thing is known in the bounded case, where one replaces handlebody with compression body.